# SwiftUI Why do i declare this in the preview?

Tags: swift, swiftui

im doing a course from Udmy and its all about fetching data from a file.
the data model we use is fruit.
so i understand why i declare the variable in the the top so i can use it in the tab view but i don't understand why i need to do so in the preview.
why i need the this line ?

```
OnBoaarding(fruits: fruitsData)
```

can anyone shine some light?

```
    import SwiftUI

   struct OnBoaarding: View {
    
var fruits: [Fruit] = fruitsData
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.white.ignoresSafeArea()
        TabView {
            ForEach(fruits[0..<8]) { item in
            FruitCardView(fruit: item)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .padding(.vertical,25)
        }.shadow(color: Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0 ,opacity: 0.3), radius: 8, x: 6, y: 6)
    }
}

struct OnBoaarding_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OnBoaarding(fruits: fruitsData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on what exactly `fruitsData` is (constant example data?) this should also work in Preview: `OnBoaarding()`

Answer (score 1):

Preview is the Canvas(similar to Simulator) inside the Xcode which shows you the preview of your view. You can see this preview/canvas at the right part of your screen.

You can remove the entire struct of Preview without any problem, but you will not be able to see the canvas.

Your main struct view is “OnBoaarding()”. You declared that inside the preview, so canvas knows what you want to display on the canvas screen.

You can actually run your view directly with simulator without this preview, but running on simulator costs more storage and performance. Preview is lighter.